# Horizon Dashboard takes too much of time to load | Openstack-Ansible

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

I want to debug the issue of Horizon Dashboard being slow, thereby taking too much of time to load. Any possible hints/references to code or something will indeed be helpful to me.

Waiting for the guided response regarding the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. You should provide some kind of code or screenshots to let us understand your issue

Comment: Hello @IoannisBarakos, the question I've put up here is kind of a general scenario/thing. I'm looking to debug this and find a solution. I'm looking for a code to start debugging and I haven't got anything. So, put it up here. Maybe someone can help or point me to debug this.

Answer (score -1):

I also met this problem, not only the openstack dashboard response slowly, but also the CLI command(Just dashboad response is more slow than it)
the results as below:

```
*[root@kolla ~]# time neutron port-list | wc -l
neutron CLI is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use openstack CLI instead.
98

real    0m16.366s
user    0m0.735s
sys     0m0.164s*



*[root@kolla ~]# time nova list | wc -l
25

real    0m10.767s
user    0m0.798s
sys     0m0.121s
[root@kolla ~]# time port list | wc -l*
```

from dashboard, it would need takes 18 seconds to get all instances of the special tenant.

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer.